# Port forwarding working on Virtualbox but not on VMware Workstation for Centos7 virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, port-forwarding, centos-7

I'm running Windows 7. I created a Centos7 virtual machine originally through Virtualbox and successfully set up port forwarding with these rules to allow SSH and HTTP:

Protocol: TCP | Host IP: 127.0.0.1 | Host Port: 2222 | Guest IP | 192.168.1.201 | Guest Port: 22

Protocol: TCP | Host IP: 127.0.0.1 | Host Port: 8080 | Guest IP | 192.168.1.201 | Guest Port: 80

I imported the virtual machine into VMware Workstation 11. I'm able to open the virtual machine fine with VMware but am unable to access it through SSH or the webserver through HTTP. I tried configuring the port forwarding with the Virtual Network Editor but I think my problem is I can't specify the host IP anywhere. I can only enter the host port (which I have as 2222 and 8080 for each respective rule), the virtual machine address (192.168.1.201) and virtual machine ports (22 and 80 respectively). Of course both are TCP. So if assuming this is the problem, then where/how could I specify the host IP of 127.0.0.1? This seems to be the only variable missing between Virtualbox which works and VMware which doesn't.